# Migrating app from Python2 to Python3 on appengine standard environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm migrating the app from python2 to python3. While migrating I found that GAE *Modules API* is not supported in python3. Below docs says that:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#modules

> You can use a combination of environment variables and the App Engine
>   Admin API to obtain information about and modify your application's
>   running services

does it mean that we need to explicitly provide the URL in yaml to call that host?

Looking for an alternate solution

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what it was you were doing with the Modules API in version 2.7 of the Python runtime that you now want to be able to implement in version 3.7?

Comment: @ChristopherP I've two microservice which I'm starting using dispatch.yaml say service1.yaml service2.yaml using dev_appserver. I'm calling the endpoint of 1st microservice from 2nd microservice, so I'm using module API to get the get_hostname of  microservice and appending the endpoint to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of making calls to the API directly, you can use the [App Engine Admin API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/appengine/v1).

Comment: Thanks, @Dustin, I'll sure look into it. 
I have a scenario where the first module is running on Python27, another one at Python37. I'm want to make RPC calls from Pytthon37 to Python27 (pubsub scenario) Is it possible using the API client library?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It doesn't sound like that would be a use case for the Admin API.